# Find & Replace Long Blocks of Text (Microsoft Word) without losing the styles

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I would like to find and replace long blocks of text with line breaks in Microsoft Word. With ctrl+h I am able to find and replace text up to 255 characters. But if I want to search for a text which has line breaks, ctrl+h does not work. So, I looked in the internet and found the following code which helped me to delete the copied text from the document. But the Macro is also removing the styles in the document.

Here is the code I took from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/find-replace-long-blocks-of-text-microsoft-word/2fa77e32-9085-4c74-9d11-04d86829442f

```
Sub Remove_text()
    Dim strText As String
    Dim strReplacement As String
    strText = Selection.Range.Text
    strReplacement = "" 'Use this command to delete the instances of the selected text
    'strReplacement = InputBox("Enter the text to be used for the replacement", "Find and replace long text")
    With ActiveDocument.Range
        .Text = Replace(.Text, strText, strReplacement)
    End With
End Sub
```

For e.g. if I run the macro with the fallowing words in a word document and run the macro after selecting two words, the resultant text will be with all the words in bold characters.

Before

- **Cow**
- **Rabbit**
- Ducks
- Shrimp
- ***Pig***
- Goat
- Crab
- Deer
- **Chicken**
- **Seagull**
- **Ostrich**

After

- **Cow**
- **Rabbit**
- **Ducks**
- **Shrimp**
- **Pig**
- **Goat**
- **Crab**
- **Deer**
- **Chicken**
- **Seagull**
- **Ostrich**

If I run the macro with the fist word in the list without bold and italics all the words are becoming plain as shown below.

Before

- Cow
- **Rabbit**
- Ducks
- Shrimp
- ***Pig***
- Goat
- Crab
- Deer
- **Chicken**
- **Seagull**
- **Ostrich**

After

- Cow
- Rabbit
- Ducks
- Shrimp
- Pig
- Goat
- Crab
- Deer
- Chicken
- Seagull
- Ostrich

The above list is just an example. The same thing also happens in a large document. In that document all the styles will be replaced with the first word's style. So the styles of the whole document is depending on the first word's style. Can someone help me to remove the text with line breaks at the same time preserve the styles?

Comment: What do you mean by "removing the styles in the document"? The code in your question only deletes text. The styles that were used to format the text will still be in the document even if they are no longer being used.

Comment: To move text along with styling, you can use the clipboard to copy and paste, or you can shuffle material into and out of AutoText/Building Blocks.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: Sorry to say that I am not an expert in VBA for Word. What I understand from the code is, ".Text" is plain text without format and in that plain text, the selected string has been replaced with empty character. I am very sorry if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: @JohnKorchok: Many thanks for your input. But I couldn't fallow you. Could you please elaborate your comment or give a sample code snippet for this.

Comment: I suggest that you work out what steps you would take without using code to achieve what you want. Then use the macro recorder to record those steps. You can then review the code, research what you don’t understand and finally edit it to improve it. You can then come back with further questions on any specific problems you encounter. You may also find it helpful to improve your understanding of styles.

Comment: Using 'strReplacement = ""' means you're replacing the found text with nothing; it has *no effect* on what Styles exist in the document's metadata (i.e. any Styles used by the deleted content will still be available for use).

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I have updated the description of my problem. Please check it once again.

Comment: @macropod, Thanks for your input. I have updated the description of my problem. Could you please check it once again.

Comment: What you have described is standard Word behaviour, whether you do things with VBA or not. The formatting is directly connected to the text. If you remove or replace the text the formatting goes too and will need to reapplied. Your question still has nothing to do with Styles in Word. Please review this article: shaunakelly.com/word/styles/tipsonstyles.html

Comment: It is impossible to remove text from a document but keep the formatting. That would be like having a bag of flavoured crisps/potato chips and wanting to throw the crisps away but keep the flavouring.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I don't think you have understood the problem. In the example, if I delete any word from the list (for e.g. crab), the word is getting deleted with the format. But the format is also changing for the other text.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt If you want a proof, just copy and paste everything in a word document and test it.

Comment: Until you are able to explain clearly what you are trying to achieve I am unable to help you further.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I would like to search for a text with line breaks and remove that text where ever it appears in a document without losing the format of that document.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing in your comments has nothing to do with the format of the document. Deleting text does not change the document's format. Deleting Section breaks, though, can do so drastically.

I note that you have radically changed your description of the problem since first posting it and receiving feedback. Clearly, you've wasted everyone's time by giving a poor problem description in the first place.

The examples in your *updated* description clearly show that you're *replacing* content, not merely deleting it. In that case, to preserve the formatting, you need to limit your replacement content to the same range as whatever exhibits the format of the content you want to replace. Either that, or you must type and format the replacement content exactly how you want it to appear, then copy it to the clipboard and use ^c for the replacement expression.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining the problem earlier. Even after explaining as best as I could, you still didn't understand the problem. I want to delete some text which has line breaks. I am deleting it by using find and replace method. Since I can't use ^h for this, I am using a Macro.

Comment: I am perfectly well aware of what you're describing and I also know for certain it **cannot** be done via '.Text = Replace(.Text, strText, strReplacement)'. All that does is replace your formatted text with unformatted text. Hence the use of the clipboard - which may also mean use Ctrl-h instead of a macro. The other possibility is the use of the .FormattedText method in a macro, but even that requires a *formatted* source to draw on.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The solutions you had mentioned don't work for me as I have large documents with more than 50 pages with different formats and font types. Please let me know if you have a simpler solution.

Comment: Using the clipboard, one could replace the text of Alice in Wonderland with War & Peace - with all the formatting intact. I see no evidence from anything you've posted to show how you've even tried to use the clipboard, let alone the .FormattedText method. In any event, your claim "if I want to search for a text which has line breaks, ctrl+h does not work" only shows you're doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer looks very cryptic for me. Due to that I have misunderstood your answer. Could you please elaborate your answer.